# No puedo editar nada (HTML, CSS, Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Cada vez que uso bootstrap, cuando intento ponerle un fondo de color a los section, padding, o una imagen de perfil, nunca cambia nada. ¿Por qué es? Gracias.

````html
```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="keywords" content="carolina,portafolio,porfolio,portfolio,web,website,página,pagina,sitio,web,app">
<meta name="author" content="Carolina">
<title>Carolina Portfolio</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="Logo" width="35" height="29" class="d-inline-block align-text-top">
      #YoProgramo
    </a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#menu" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M19 0h-14c-2.761 0-5 2.239-5 5v14c0 2.761 2.239 5 5 5h14c2.762 0 5-2.239 5-5v-14c0-2.761-2.238-5-5-5zm-11 19h-3v-11h3v11zm-1.5-12.268c-.966 0-1.75-.79-1.75-1.764s.784-1.764 1.75-1.764 1.75.79 1.75 1.764-.783 1.764-1.75 1.764zm13.5 12.268h-3v-5.604c0-3.368-4-3.113-4 0v5.604h-3v-11h3v1.765c1.396-2.586 7-2.777 7 2.476v6.759z"/></svg>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M12 0c-6.626 0-12 5.373-12 12 0 5.302 3.438 9.8 8.207 11.387.599.111.793-.261.793-.577v-2.234c-3.338.726-4.033-1.416-4.033-1.416-.546-1.387-1.333-1.756-1.333-1.756-1.089-.745.083-.729.083-.729 1.205.084 1.839 1.237 1.839 1.237 1.07 1.834 2.807 1.304 3.492.997.107-.775.418-1.305.762-1.604-2.665-.305-5.467-1.334-5.467-5.931 0-1.311.469-2.381 1.236-3.221-.124-.303-.535-1.524.117-3.176 0 0 1.008-.322 3.301 1.23.957-.266 1.983-.399 3.003-.404 1.02.005 2.047.138 3.006.404 2.291-1.552 3.297-1.23 3.297-1.23.653 1.653.242 2.874.118 3.176.77.84 1.235 1.911 1.235 3.221 0 4.609-2.807 5.624-5.479 5.921.43.372.823 1.102.823 2.222v3.293c0 .319.192.694.801.576 4.765-1.589 8.199-6.086 8.199-11.386 0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12z"/></svg>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <!-- Button trigger modal -->
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
            Acceder
          </button>

          <!-- Modal -->
          <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Iniciar sesión</h1>
                  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Correo electrónico:</label>
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Escribí tu correo">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Contraseña:</label>
                      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Escribí tu contraseña">
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="form-check">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Recordarme</label>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Acceder</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>


  <header>
<div id="carouselExampleAutoplaying" class="carousel slide" height="500px" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://www.bustedcubicle.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Industry-Disrupted-Programming-main-banner.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://d2gg9evh47fn9z.cloudfront.net/800px_COLOURBOX30297152.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://biox.stanford.edu/sites/default/files/binary_banner.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>

  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleAutoplaying" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Anterior</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleAutoplaying" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Siguiente</span>
  </button>
</div>
  </header>

  <section>
<div class="container text-center">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <img class="img-fluid rounded-circle" width="200px" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1551625864-3e291c567ab2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1yZWxhdGVkfDE1fHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
      <h2>Carolina *texto en itálica*</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <h3>Sobre mí</h3> <!-- hab,id,full -->
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque, dolorem eveniet tempora perferendis quia praesentium repellat tempore, quas facere nulla est optio. Deserunt aliquid ullam esse dolor atque reprehenderit eum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>


  </section>


</body>
</html>
````

Comment: Hola Carolina, sería buena idea que nos mostrarás tu **css**, para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Hola! Mi css está totalmente vacío. Pero para agregar fondo hacía

*{ 
background-color: red
}
también intenté 
body{ 
background-color: red }, section { background-color: red } y nada. También fui super específica con el contenido, es decir, intenté "section, container, row, col", Le indiqué la clase pero ninguna forma surgió efecto. Ya no sé qué hacer porque mis modificaciones a cualquier cosa no se aplican.

Comment: Estás segura que tu **css** se llama **style.css** y que está ubicado dentro de la carpeta "css"?.

Comment: si, se llama así y está en esa carpeta

Comment: tu html esta en el mismo directorio de la carpeta css?, porque yo lo estoy probando y funciona.

Comment: Algunas veces las cosas más simples nos dan dolores de cabeza... quitale la primer barra a **<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">**, para que quede **<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">** y... boileau!!

Comment: Jajaja es cierto, lo acabo de hacer. Ahora es "css/style.css". Pero tampoco me deja cambiar el fondo. ¿A vos sí? ¿Qué escribiste? ¿Será mi IDE o mi extensión visualizador? En las dos computadoras me pasaba lo mismo.

Comment: la carpeta css está en el mismo directorio que el html?, porque yo estoy usando lo que vos escribiste.

Comment: En la carpeta "proyecto" está ese index.html, también hay una carpeta que se llama css, donde está style.css.  ¿Te referís a eso? Saqué al css de esa carpeta y cambié la dirección en el html para más comodidad pero tampoco funciona. Por las dudas copié el código en un visualizador online, codepen, y se puso todo rojo y después todo mi código arriba, pero con el fondo blanco. Entonces supongo que funciona y mis códigos de bootstrap tienen fondo blanco? No estoy segura de eso, debería ser transparente, no les puse fondo ni nada... Mi idea es que la foto y el texto tengan fondo rojo.

Comment: que browser usas?

Comment: Mi navegador es Google Chrome, uso Visual Studio Code y la página es Codepen. Mi computadora es bien bien antigua.

Comment: en algún lugar del chrome, hay una opción para desarrolladores, entra ahi, y busca Style Editor

Comment: estás ejecutando desde el ide? si es así, proba darle click al index.html.

Comment: Eso me sirvió, gracias. Con el inspector pude ver que ese apartado era section, entonces me funcionó section{ background-color:red } en lugar de body. Pero solo se ve bien en Codepen no en VSC, aunque lo reinicie.

Comment: proba darle directo al index, tiene que funcionar, tu código está perfecto.

Comment: Eso hago pero se ve igual que antes cuando uso VSC... Y eso que el código es el mismo. No es la primera vez que me pasa. No sé que hago para que falle así, porque en mi otra computadora también me pasaba.

Comment: En conclusión, con el inspector vi que hice y seleccioné mal los elementos, además de que mi visualizador en vsc funciona mal. Ya está solucionado. Solo me queda ver cómo ejecutar bien mi código, gracias ><

Comment: Primero en el head llama a tu css propio después de llamar a los archivos css de Bootstrap, y los js de bootstrap siempre abajo del todo., antes de la etiqueta de cierre del body